# Get districts bordering given district

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I want to get the geometries of the districts bordering a given district.

```
districts
d0 = districts[0]
gpd.sjoin(d0, districts, op='intersects')
```

This gives the geometry of d0 in each row. But I want the geometry of the right table in each row. Is it possible to get both left and right table geometries?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `join` to get the geometry from the right table after your sjoin

```
 gdf = gpd.sjoin(d0, districts, op='intersects')
```

gdf will have a column/series called `index_right`which we can leverage

```
gdf.join(districts['geometry'], on='index_right', lsuffix='', rsuffix='_districts')
```

Not sure how geopandas will handle two geometries.  I'm guessing all operations will leverage the original one from d0